# Visual Studio Custom Build Default Directory Incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My Visual Studio 2013 Custom Build Tool step is failing because the directory in which the step is being executed is not the directory where the project file is (which was by default the case up until recently). I can patch it by adding a `cd` command to the start of the step to change to the project directory but I was wondering if anyone could tell me

1. how this directory path is set
2. how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The build always assumes the project directory as 'base' directory.
This gives msbuild a set location (Builds to bin\debug is a subfolder off 'Base', reference hint paths and a lot more besides).

I would just change the execute of your tool to be reference based (i.e ....\tool.exe or similar) or make use of the path environment variables ($(OutDir),$(TargetPath),$(ProjectPath),$(TargetDir) etc).
Another option that I make use of is to have a batch file called 'post.bat' that has the necessary steps to execute a custom tool.  This is then placed in the project folder and added to the project as an artefact.

Without knowing exactly where your custom tool resides relative to the project (or solution) or what the 'working directory' requirements of the custom tool are I cannot suggest more.